# Creating area chart from csv file containing multiple values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a model that produces an output in csv. The columns are as follows (just an fictive example):

```
|    Car    |    Price    |    Year    |
```

The car column has different car manufacturers for example, with an average car price for each year in column 'Price'.

Example

```
|    Car    |    Price    |    Year   |

|    BMW    |    34000    |    1990   |

|    BMW    |    35000    |    1991   |

|    BMW    |    37000    |    1993   |

|    AUDI   |    32000    |    1991   |

|    AUDI   |    33500    |    1992   |

|    AUDI   |    34000    |    1993   |

|    AUDI   |    35500    |    1994   |

|    SEAT   |    25600    |    1994   |
...
```

I would like to be able to plot:

1. An area chart with all the prices for each car manufacturer in the years that the prices are available, within a 20 year period (for example 1990-2010).
2. Some years, there is no price available for some of the car manufacturers, and for that reason not all car manufacturer has 20 rows of data in the csv, the output just skips the whole year and row. See the BWM in the example, lacking 1992.

Since I run the model with different inputs, the actual names of the "Cars" change (and so do the prices), so I need the code to pick up a certain car name and then plot the available values for each run.
This is just an example for simplification, but the layout of the actual data is the same. Would much appreciate some help on this one!

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think this might work. Also, I am not a pro just a beginner

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
med_path = "path for csv file"
med = pd.read_csv(med_path)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=120)
area = pd.DataFrame(prices, columns=[‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’]) # in the places of a,b,c replace with years
area.plot(kind=’area’,ax=ax)
plt.title(‘Graph for Area plot’)
plt.show()
```

I think this might not be an ideal way to hardcode all the values but you can use `for` loop to iterate through the csv file's content

Comment: For the 'a', 'b', 'c' part, do you want me to put columns=['y'] for the year column which has the name 'y' in my file, or should I state all the years one by one like '1990', '1991', '1992' etc?

I get an error in the "area =" row. It says:
NameError: name 'prices' is not defined (even though I changed it to what my actual value should be based on my excel).

Comment: yeah! make the values of years as a list so that you can loop through it right?

Comment: The years are now written as a list, but it does not work due to the fact that the first parameter, prices, is not defined. 

'<ipython-input-59-87c38c1265b3> in <module>
      6 fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=120)
      7 df.columns
----> 8 area = pd.DataFrame(ProductionByTechnologyAnnual, columns=['2020', '2021', '2022', '2023','2024', '2025','2026','2027','2028','2029','2030','2031','2032','2033','2034','2035','2036','2037','2038','2039','2040'])
     9 area.plot(kind='area',ax=ax)

NameError: name 'ProductionByTechnologyAnnual' is not defined'

Comment: Or do it this way! first, make a loop through the car column and make them store in a variable where the car names are the same. You can use this line ```df.loc[df['car'] == BMW]```. Now you can loop through limited values right. If you store the values as BMW now you can loop through the price and year easily. So that it will be easy enough to continue.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Sasidhar, unfortunately it does not work. Whatever value or name I write after the `==` sign, it states that the name is not defined for that value. Even though I can see the names when printing out `df.head()`